# Customer Attention email

Tags: email, customer-portal, apex-email-service, portal

The email that is sent to a portal user when their case is updated (to Customer Attention) comes from the an employee that updated the case. Can we have it come from noreply@mycompany.com instead?

The email that is sent to a portal user when their case is updated (to Customer Attention) comes from the an employee that updated the case. Can we have it come from noreply@mycompany.com instead?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is appropriate for a portal but have you looked at org wide email addresses? https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=orgwide_email.htm&language=en_US